# Restricting exposure of Secret File Contents in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, security, azure-devops

I was exploring the security persona of Azure DevOps Secret Files. Based on my analysis the below works well in terms of security POV,

1. Content's are not visible in the UI
2. A Print Step ( Cat  ) doesn't actually print the content.

Where it fails,

1. Move the secure file to BuildArtifact and publish the files. It then become accessible.

Is there a way to restrict the above activity? Or any better way to manage the secret in the secure file.

Comment: To restrict access to secure files in Azure DevOps, you can limit access to the pipeline or project where the file is used. Additionally, you can use Azure Key Vault to store and manage secrets, and then use the Azure Key Vault task in your pipeline to retrieve the secrets at runtime. This way, the secrets are not stored in the pipeline or in any artifacts that are published.
If you need to use secure files, you can limit their exposure by restricting access to the pipeline or project where they are used. You can also encrypt the files and use Azure Key Vault to store the encryption keys.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the Azure Key Vault task in your pipeline to retrieve the keys at runtime and decrypt the files. This way, the files are not stored in plaintext in the pipeline or in any artifacts that are published.

Comment: References:

-   [Protecting secrets in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/secrets?view=azure-devops#use-secret-variables)
-   [Use Azure Key Vault secrets in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops#run-and-review-the-pipeline)
-   [Security considerations for mission-critical workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/containers/aks-mission-critical/mission-critical-security#secure-deployments)

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help

Answer (score 0):

When we use the Download secure file task to download the secure file to Pipeline agents, the secure file will be processed as a normal file.

Therefore when uploading build artifacts, security files can be uploaded.

I'm afraid there's currently no good enough method to avoid this behavior in Azure DevOps.

For a workaround, we can use [.artifactignore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/artifactignore?view=azure-devops) file to exclude the secure file when uploading the build artifacts. But this approach also has limitations.

Even if we use other ways to store secure files (e.g. azure key vault). When we download the file in the pipeline agent, it will still be processed as an ordinary file.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.